# PHP session Login and Logout fails to proceed immediately

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I have a PHP site with Login and Logout, using `$_SESSION['userName']` to store the `username` of the logged in member.

But when people login, this does not happen immediately due to some reason. The same with the Logout script: It works, but not immediately. I have to try about 2-4 times before something happens.

Here is my Login code and Logout code:

Code:  /login.php

```
session_start();
//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
$host        =    'host';
$user        =    'username';
$password    =    'password';
//=============Data Base Information=================
$database    =    'database';

$conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information 
is not Correct'); //Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

//===============End Server Configuration============

//*******Form Information********

$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$passWord=md5($password); // Encrypted Password

//*********retrieving data from Database**********

$query = "select * from users where userName='$userName' and passWord='$passWord'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

//**********if $userName and $passWord will match database, The above function 
//**********will return 1 row

if($rows==1)

//***if the userName and password matches then register a session and redrect 
//***user to the Successfull.php
{
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
else
{
    echo 'Incorrect username or password.';
}
exit;
```

Code:  /logout.php

```
session_name('userName');
session_start('userName');
session_unset('userName');
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
```

I really hope you can help me with this issue.

## Edit 1:   Okay now the login works, and the logout can now log the user out of all pages EXEPT the page the user where on, when they clicked "logout" ... Any ideas?

Comment: Try this for your logout file: session_start(); session_destroy(); header("Location:index.php");

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, Whenever you need session variables on the page. you must start session first on the same page.

By adding

session_start();

before any output message or character to the browser, else it will show a warning message.

lets come to the later part logout function.
where you should use
session_destroy();
to kill all the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

a) perhaps browser cache is working, try add the following instructions before doing anything:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

b) notice: session_start does not seem to have any parameter supported

Comment: I'm glad you guy are trying to help, but the user still dosn't get logged out :(